# Doubts on Authentication Techniques - Passport

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-jwt

So I was trying out the authentication techniques with `passport` and `passport-jwt` with the express server. Here is the code I've been working with

```
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
const User = require("../models/user");
const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = "secret";
module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
            User.findById(jwt_payload.id,(err,user)=>{
                if(err){
                    return done(err,false);
                }
                if(user){
                    done(null,user);
                }
                else{
                    done(null,false);
                }
            })
        })
    )
};
```

So the all point of using this passport authorization is to minimize the number of times the database is accessed, right?

But in this code after extracting the token, the database is accessed through the `findById` method to find whether the user is in the database, so what's the point in all of this if the database is accessed during each authentication request?

I'm pretty sure I'm saying something wrong, some help in clarifying this matter is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The point is- "Simple, unobtrusive authentication for Node.js". Number of queries made is not an optimization that is it's top priority.

Comment: You're implying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, why would you need to do `User.findById` on the middleware?

You don't have to access the database on the middleware to find whether user exists or not from the JWT payload. When the user is getting the jwt through the `/login` endpoint, you should've already checked whether the user exists or not

```js
// just a logic example on the login enpoint

const user = User.findUserByEmail(req.body.email);
if (!user) res.sendStatus(401); //returns 401 if user not found
else {
    if (verifyPassword(req.body.password, password)) {
        res.send(generatedJwtWithUserIdOnThePayload)
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401); //returns 401 if password invalid
    }
}
```

The jwt that's passed when logging in to the client already had valid user id in it, therefore you dont need to get `User` document from `User.findById` everytime client sending a request to your other endpoint.

Since user id is already inside the payload, unless you need other data beside user id from `User` document, you don't really need to do `User.findById` on the middleware

Comment: Ok that solves it, the code I posted was widely seen in so many examples, that's why I followed it. Thanks btw.